# Unexpectedly recieving "std::out_of_range" error while using the same function

Tags: c++, string, function, recursion, char

I've written a recursive palindrome function that in first code receives only a word, and in second code receives a sentence. Yet unexpectedly second code is giving me "out of range" error.

this function (which is working correctly) is used in both codes:

```
bool palindrome( string str, int first, int last )
{
    if( first == str.size() - 1 ) //if string is a single alphabet.
        return true;
    if( str[ first ] == str[ last ] )
        return palindrome( str.substr( first + 1, last - 1 ), first, last - 2 );
}
```

in first code it works as intended even if I input a very long string:

```
int main()
{
    string str = "madamhelloollehmadam";
    palindrome( str, 0, str.size() - 1 ) ? cout << "palindrome!" << '\n' : cout << "not palindrome." << '\n';
}
```

In second code, I need to convert the input sentence to a word, also making all characters to lowercase (i do all these in other functions). I literally inputed same string in second code yet still i get error at bottom of page:

```
int main()
{
    string str = "madam hello olleh madam"; //this becomes "madamhelloollehmadam" after going to "normalString" function.
    palindrome( normalString(str), 0, normalString(str).size() - 1 ) ? cout << "palindrome!" << '\n' : cout << "not palindrome." << '\n';
}
```

This is the error I get (I won't get this error for first code that gets a word and not a sentence yet both "palindrome" functions are the same. I'm guessing something is wrong with "normalString" function yet I couldn't detect any size differences ...)

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted
```

also this is normalString function:

```
string normalString( string str )
{
    vector<string> vec;
    for( int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i )
        vec.push_back( charToString(str[ i ]) );

    for( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i )
    {
        if( !isAlpha( vec[ i ] ) )
            vec[ i ].erase();
        if( isupper( stringToChar(vec[ i ]) ) ) 
            vec[ i ] = charToString( tolower( stringToChar( vec[ i ] ) ) );
    } 

    string str2 = vectorToString( vec );
    return str2;
}
```

This is all of my second code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

bool palindrome( string, int, int );
bool isAlpha( string );
string charToString( char );
string normalString( string );
char stringToChar( string );
string vectorToString( vector<string> );

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a word or a sentence: ";

    string str;
    while( cin >> str )
    {
        palindrome( normalString(str), 0, normalString(str).size() - 1 ) ? cout << str << " is palindrome!" << " (" << normalString(str) << ") " 
                                                    << '\n' : cout << str << " is not palindrome!" << " (" << normalString(str) << ") " << '\n';    
        cout << "Enter a word or a sentence: ";
    }
    return 0;
}

string vectorToString( vector<string> vec )
{
    stringstream ss;
    for( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i )
        ss << vec[ i ];
    string str;
    ss >> str;
    return str;
}

string charToString( char c )
{
    stringstream ss;
    string s;
    ss << c;
    ss >> s;
    return s;
}

char stringToChar( string str )
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    char c;
    ss >> c;
    return c;
}

bool isAlpha( string s )
{
    return s == "a" || s == "b" || s == "c" || s == "d" || s == "e" || s == "f" || s == "g" || s == "h" || s == "i" || s == "j" || s == "k" || s == "l"||
           s == "m" || s == "n" || s == "o" || s == "p" || s == "q" || s == "r" || s == "s" || s == "t" || s == "u" || s == "v" || s == "w" || s == "x"||
           s == "y" || s == "z" ||
           s == "A" || s == "B" || s == "C" || s == "D" || s == "E" || s == "F" || s == "G" || s == "H" || s == "I" || s == "J" || s == "K" || s == "L"||
           s == "M" || s == "N" || s == "O" || s == "P" || s == "Q" || s == "R" || s == "S" || s == "T" || s == "U" || s == "V" || s == "W" || s == "X"||
           s == "Y" || s == "Z" ; 
}

string normalString( string str )
{
    vector<string> vec;
    for( int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i )
        vec.push_back( charToString(str[ i ]) );

    for( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i )
    {
        if( !isAlpha( vec[ i ] ) )
            vec[ i ].erase();
        if( isupper( stringToChar(vec[ i ]) ) ) 
            vec[ i ] = charToString( tolower( stringToChar( vec[ i ] ) ) );
    } 

    string str2 = vectorToString( vec );
    return str2;
}

bool palindrome( string str, int first, int last )
{
    if( first == str.size() - 1 ) //if string is a single alphabet.
        return true;
    if( str[ first ] == str[ last ] )
        return palindrome( str.substr( first + 1, last - 1 ), first, last - 2 );
}
```

Comment: I'm testing your code and the first 'madamhelloollehmadam' also throws the error btw

Comment: Here's a hint: The second argument to `substr` is not an index, but a length.

Comment: @travisjayday I just tested again "madamhelloollehmadam" It is working and no errors. here is my first code: https://pastebin.com/3YMAMerx

Comment: That this is unexpected proves that it's working. If it was expected, it wouldn't be exceptional behaviour. If it's not exceptional, it's not an exception.

Comment: @AndyG I'm sending "First" which is alwasy "0" to substr as second argument. Aren't I??? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Looks like the old code's `palindrome` function has all of its `return` statements in `if`s. This allows the possibility of entering none of the ifs `if`s and not `return`ing. Not valid code.

Comment: Second code has the same problem. Crank up your compiler warning level. This should be in the warning list.

Comment: @user4581301 the old and new palindorme functions are the same... only inputs to function is changed. function is literally copy/pasted to code 2.

Comment: There are so many errors in this code it's hard to know where to begin. If there's anyone at all you can talk to in person, that would be best.

Comment: @mhm: Do you really believe that the second argument in this code: `str.substr( first + 1, last - 1 )` is 1) `first` and 2) "always zero" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with this code.

### The palindrome function

First, let's rewrite the signature a little bit. Since `palindrome` doesn't need a copy of the string, we pass in a const reference instead. The indexes should also be changed to `std::size_t` because that is the type used for indexing strings.

```
bool palindrome(const std::string &str, std::size_t first, std::size_t last) {
```

Next, we need to handle the case where the string only has one characters… but it is *also* important to handle the case where the string has zero.  Here's the original code:

```
    // if (first == str.size() - 1) // Wrong!
```

First of all, this doesn't do what it says. The length of the string we are processing is supposed to be from `first` to `last`, not from `first` to `size() - 1` (otherwise why does `last` even exist?)  Second of all, this won't work if `size()` is 0. It will overflow! Here is the corrected code.

```
    // Empty string, or only one character
    std::size_t length = last - first;
    if (length <= 1)
        return true;
```

Next, we compare the first and last character. But the last character isn't actually `str[last]`, it's `str[last-1]`.

```
    if (str[first] == str[last - 1])
```

Since we have the convenient `first` and `last` parameter, let's use them instead of calling `substr`:

```
        return palindrome(str, first + 1, last - 1);
```

But we have to remember to return if the condition fails...

```
    return false;
}
```

### The normalString function

It turns out that `std::string` has `push_back`, so you don't need a vector, and `isAlpha` can be changed to operate on `char` instead of `string`, which makes it much simpler.

```
bool isAlpha(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

std::string normalString(std::string str) {
    std::string result;
    for (char c : str) {
        if (isAlpha(c))
            result.push_back(std::tolower(c));
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Full code

Also removed `using namespace std;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>

bool palindrome(const std::string &, std::size_t, std::size_t);
std::string normalString(std::string);

int main() {
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter a word or a sentence: ";
        std::string str;
        if (!(std::cin >> str))
            break;
        str = normalString(str);
        if (palindrome(str, 0, str.size())) {
            std::cout << str << " is palindrome!"
                << " (" << str << ")\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << str << " is not palindrome!"
                << " (" << normalString(str) << ") \n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isAlpha(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

std::string normalString(std::string str) {
    std::string result;
    for (char c : str) {
        if (isAlpha(c))
            result.push_back(std::tolower(c));
    }
    return result;
}

bool palindrome(const std::string &str, std::size_t first, std::size_t last) {
    // Empty string, or only one character
    std::size_t length = last - first;
    if (length <= 1)
        return true;
    if (str[first] == str[last - 1])
        return palindrome(str, first + 1, last - 1);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Debug in Visual Studio, you can pinpoint the problem to a specific line.

So here's your problem: in function `normalString(string)` you must do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    if (!isAlpha(vec[i]))
        vec[i].erase();
    else if (isupper(stringToChar(vec[i])))  //this is where your error was. use visual studio to debug your application 
        vec[i] = charToString(tolower(stringToChar(vec[i])));
}
```

You were tying to use the function `isupper` on a weird character which made your program crash. If you use an else if statement, it'll work because it won't try to invoke isupper() if it's not a alpha character.

The lesson: use Visual Studio debug mode

EDIT: I believe you tried to do this `isupper('{0}')`. isupper() does not like string terminators apparently (it'll crash)

Comment: Removing stuff like this in the loop is O(n^2) for no good reason. Also, you have to cast to `unsigned char` before passing stuff to `tolower`.

Comment: yes, I agree. @Dietrich Epp's answer is most probably better, but this would have been a quick fix for the OP. I wanted him to appreciate and learn the value of Debugging a program so that he can figure out problems like this one by himself in the future.

Comment: I use only Linux for programming (gedit ) and use terminal for debugging... thanks

Comment: @travisjayday I'm not sure this is the problem since anything I throw at this function it just turns it into a word...